# Export and Import documents with UUID from MongoDB Compass Windows Application

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, uuid, mongodb-compass

### Summary

**How to preserve UUIDs when exporting and importing documents?**

1. Export collection as JSON file
2. Drop collection and re-create collection
3. Import JSON file
4. UUIDs are converted to `Binary('bsOPwpzDrcKCcE0Iwr1FwrHDn8KRfsKdw7U=', 0)`
5. Cannot read documents from code anymore due to 4.

### Details

I needed to remove a field from all documents in a collection, so I thought about exporting all documents in that collection and import them again. During the import, I can deselect the field I wanted to remove, which is exactly what I needed.

However..

The documents in this collection contain UUIDs: one for the ID of the document, one for the ID of another document in another collection.

After exporting, all the UUIDs have been converted to

```
{
  "$binary": 
  {
    "base64": "QDhscRPCgUAcwqLDosOwPDDDu8KNBA==",
    "subType": "00"
}
```

When I import the json file back into the collection, all the documents UUIDs are replaced with

```
Binary('bsOPwpzDrcKCcE0Iwr1FwrHDn8KRfsKdw7U=', 0)
```

When I try to get those documents from code (C#) I get

> An error occurred while deserializing the Id property of class
> MongoDbGenericRepository.Models.Document: Expected length to be 16,
> not 29.

### Things I tried

When you import a document on MongoDB Compass, you get a dropdown that lets you change the field type:
[image]

- I have tried changing that to UUID.
- I have tried to change the type to UUID as above and also manually edit the `"subType": "00"` in the JSON export file to both `03` and `04`.
  When I did this, the documents actually had UUID fields instead of `Binary('bsOPwpzDrcKCcE0Iwr1FwrHDn8KRfsKdw7U=', 0)`. However, I still get the same error about the expected length when trying to get those documents from code.
- I have tried to change the `"subType": "00"` to both `03` and `04` and keep the field type as Binary. When I did this, the document came up with `Binary('bsOPwpzDrcKCcE0Iwr1FwrHDn8KRfsKdw7U=', 3)`, but I would still get the same error from code.

So now I'm stuck with a bunch of documents that have all the UUIDs messed up and cannot use them anymore :(

Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Alternatively, any suggestions on how to backup and restore for this situation?

### EDIT:

I was able to export and import **one** document. Steps:

1. Copy all the UUIDs of the document to notepad
2. Export document to JSON file
3. For each UUID, use [this site](https://toolslick.com/conversion/data/guid?#) to convert the UUID to a base64 string
4. Replace the `"base64"` value in the JSON file with the string you got in step 3
5. Import JSON document and set fields that will store those UUIDs to `UUID` (it will be `Binary` by default)

This workaround works. However, it becomes unpractical when you have many documents, and even worse if these documents reference other documents by UUID. Therefore, this workaround is not really a solution unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think the problem here is with the export // import if it is infact importing without errors. But in your C# Model, what is the attribute property you are using for the `Id` ? If I remember correct it should be `Guid `

Comment: @Pogrindis it is using the default Id property that comes with the nuget package "MongoDbGenericRepository", which is a ```Guid``` marked with ```[BsonId]```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and what I did was to edit the document using [Robo3T](https://robomongo.org/), and then copying/pasting it's contents.